# Android handler

Tags: android, gridview, handler

I am using an `AlertDialog` to display images from file, but when I press the button to show the dialog, the app to stop freezing for 6 seconds and then show the alert dialog.

My code:

```
listView_prev.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, final View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            //listview click event handling
            TextView id = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView17);
            final int id_To_Search = Integer.valueOf(id.getText().toString());
            Cursor item=mydb.singlecons(id_To_Search);
            Cursor att=mydb.attrs(id_To_Search);
            Cursor picloc=mydb.singleconspic(id_To_Search);
            att.moveToFirst();
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            //  Log.d("temp",att.getColumnName(1));

            while (!att.isAfterLast())
            {
                int l=att.getColumnCount();
                Log.d("length", String.valueOf(l));
                for(int i=2;i<l;i++){
                    Log.d("for","for");
                    if(att.getString(i)!=null){
                        String b= att.getColumnName(i)+" "+att.getString(i);
                        list.add(b);
                        Log.d("att",b);
                    }
                }
                Log.d("while","while");
                att.moveToNext();
            }
            att.close();
            Log.d("list", String.valueOf(list));
            picloc.moveToFirst();

            FilePathStrings = new String[picloc.getCount()];
            int i=0;
            while (!picloc.isAfterLast()){
                Log.d("picloc",picloc.getString(2));
                FilePathStrings[i]=picloc.getString(2);
                i++;
                picloc.moveToNext();
            }

            item.moveToFirst();

            AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Consultation.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_label_editor, null);
            dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

            TextView con=(TextView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textView29);
            con.setText("Consultation on "+item.getString(4));
            TextView des=(TextView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textView28);
            des.setText(item.getString(2));
            TextView pre=(TextView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textView31);
            pre.setText(item.getString(3));
            TextView fee=(TextView)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textView32);
            fee.setText(item.getString(5));
            adapter1 = new GridViewAdapter(FilePathStrings,getApplicationContext());
            grid = (GridView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            grid.setAdapter(adapter1);
            grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + FilePathStrings[position]), "image/*");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();
```

Gridviewadapter.java

```
class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private String[] filepath;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
GridViewAdapter(String[] fpath,Context context) {
    filepath = fpath;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}
public int getCount() {
    return filepath.length;

}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, null);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath[position]);

   Bitmap thumbBitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath[position]),320,240);

    image.setImageBitmap(thumbBitmap);

        return vi;
}
}
```

How can i resolve this issue? I know a `handler` will help here, can anybody help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: Can you again tell me whats the issue and what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: I need to remove those freeze time when cliking on the listview

Comment: Do not create new objects every time you click ..and if you can do your task on the background thread

Comment: an yoou exolain.?

Answer (score 1):

> I want the app to freeze for 6 seconds and then show the alert dialog

On `onItemClick` method doing 3-4 db operations by calling `singlecons,attrs,singleconspic` methods and also reading data from `Cursor's`. this will show UI Thread without doing anything.

Suggestion is, Instead of `Handler`, use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for calling all DB methods and getting data from Cursor's.

*Put wait for 6 seconds `doInBackground` before returning data to `onPostExecute`*

Comment: My app freezes when i click on list view because of heavy process load while showing image in alert dialog.... How can i solve this...

Comment: @Tom: Already explained in Answer use `AsyncTask ` let me known if getting any issue doing it using `AsyncTask`

Comment: when it contains  no image, the alertdialog is working perfectly, all the cursor fetchings are working quickly.... When image conatins it freezes.... Cursor only hold the locations of the imgss... So where i can use asynctask.?

Comment: @Tom: Move code from `Cursor item=mydb.singlecons(id_To_Search);` to `item.moveToFirst();` line in `doInBackground` and from `AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Consultation.this);` to `alertDialog.show();` in `onPostExecute` then check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132387/discussion-between--k-and-tom).

Answer (score 0):

Your app is freezing for seconds because you are doing the query operation to DB on the Main thread. Main thread getting blocked shows the lagging in the UI.

Yes you can use AsyncTask for this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: when there is no image file then its ok....every cursor operation is working perfectly....